# How can I import 2 module in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Guys I'm new in Python and I'm trying to understand modules.I have a folder in desktop and there are 2 module in that folder. One of them is pr.py ,it's takes a array and displays it.And other one is fillArray.py.Now I want to add these 2 friend into interpreter but when I used in interpreter `import pr.py` or `import fillArray` it's giving to me this error

```
>>> import pr
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import pr
ImportError: No module named pr
```

Then if I clicked f5(run) in `pr.py` module ,write again in interpreter `import pr` it works.That's ok.But trying to run `fillArray.py` module same steps, it's restart interpreter and it works but`pr.py` module is removing.How can I handle this?By the way this can be unnecessary but I'm using python2.7.

**Edit**:I wrote print.py sorry it should be pr.py

Comment: You probably shouldn't name it the same thing as a built in

Comment: Are you in that same folder? You have gotta be. And change the name from `print` to something else. It's a keyword in python 2.7

Comment: I have no idea what "it works but `pr.py` module is removing" is supposed to mean. But it sounds like you're not running `fillArray.py` from a working directory that contains `pr.py`.

Comment: I'm sorry my english is so bad.I'm trying to say for example in pr.py module I run it (click f5) then in interpreter import pr is working but when I run fillArray.py shell restart and pr.py module is gone I mean I cannot using it it's giving same error

Answer (score 0):

If you have both the modules in the same folder, you can use `.` which specifies current directory as follows:

```
from .pr import *
```

This statement will import all functions of `print.py` which is in the current directory

If you want specific things to be imported, just specify using their names

```
from .pr import myfunc1, myfunc2, myclass1, myclass2
```

If you wish to import the whole module, use:

```
from . import pr
```

Hope this helps :)